# \newcommand is undefined control sentence

Tags: macros

I am trying to create a very simple new command such as follows:

```
\newcommand{\rvm}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

My text is organized in a main tex file and the sections are in other files. I call them using `\input` in the main `.tex` file.

However, no matter when I call it, the `\newcommand` is undefined. The tex editor returns the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \rvm{test}
```

Is it something about the template I am using? I tried it in other documents and it works. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You are asking about the template being the culprit -- well, we don't see your template :-( Did you defined that  `\newcommand` in a group, e.g. in an environment?

Comment: the error message that you show is not the form that tex uses (which always has a command (not an argument) at the end of the line, showing the command that is undefined. Show the exact error from the log file from `!` to `?`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is very unclear however...

If you have

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\rvm}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\rvm{test}

\end{document}
```

then the error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\rvm #1->\textcolor 
                    {red}{#1}
l.7 \rvm{test}

?
```

Note the specific formatting with a linebreak after `\textcolor` indicating that that is the undefined command, occurring in the expansion, on line 7, of `\rvm{test}` (as shown on the final line of the message).

Adding

```
\usepackage{color}
```

to the preamble defines `\textcolor` and gets rid of the error.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\rvm}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\rvm{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @mad you were lucky:-) next time try to put a few more clues into the question:-)